# Python recursion what am I missing

Tags: python, search, recursion

I have a problem with 2 jugs. 
initial state is [0,0], capacity of each jug is [4,9], goal state is [0,6]
legal moves: fill jug 1 or jug 2 till the end, empty jug 1 or jug 2 and poor one jug into the other one.

```
import search #get the interface
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
class two_jugs(search.Nodes):

    #return the starting state vessel 1: 0, vessel 2: 0
    def start(self):
            return [0,0]

    #returns true if node is equal to goal node
    def goal(self,node):
            return node ==(0,6)
    #yields the successors of the configuration indicated by node
    def succ(self,node):             
            # set capacities for vessel 1: 4, vessel 2 : 9
            c = [4,9];
            #stop at second last
            for i in range(len(node)-1):
                    #create a safety copy
                    new_node = node[:]

                    #fill vessel 1
                    if new_node[i]<=0:
                            new_node[i]=c[i]
                            print new_node

                    #fill vessel 2
                    if new_node[i+1]<=0:
                            new_node[i+1]=c[i+1]
                            print new_node

                    #dump vessel i+1
                    if (new_node[i+1]>0):
                            new_node[i+1]=0
                            print new_node

                    #poor vessel i to vessel i+1                
                    if (new_node[i+1]<c[i+1] and new_node[i]>0):
                            #calculate the difference
                            d = min(new_node[i],c[i+1]-new_node[i+1])
                            new_node[i]= new_node[i]-d
                            new_node[i+1]= new_node[i+1]+d
                            print new_node

                    #dump vessel i
                    if (new_node[i]>0):
                            new_node[i]=0
                            print new_node


               #poor vessel i+1 to vessel 1
                    if (new_node[i]<c[i] and new_node[i+1]>0):
                            #calculate the difference
                            d = min(new_node[i+1],c[i]-new_node[i])
                            #set new node
                            new_node[i+1]= new_node[i+1]-d
                            new_node[i]= new_node[i]+d
                            yield new_node
                            print new_node
```

The question is since I have declared all the legal moves, why does my program return only the result of one legal move? Eg from starting state [0,0] when i run the program it returns [4,0],[0,4],[0,9] and other possible results untill the recursion stops but not my goal state.
What am I missing?

breadth_first_search class:

```
def breadth_first_search(problem, candidates):
    if not candidates: return
    # make sure there is something in the candidate list
    # I am modifying ’candidates’ list here.
    # Why don’t I need to copy?
    c = candidates.pop(0) # pop from front
    node = c[-1] # must exist
    if problem.goal(node): return c
    # base case
    succ = [s for s in problem.succ(node)]
    for s in problem.succ(node):
        candidates.append(c + [s])
        # 1-step extension
    return breadth_first_search(problem, candidates)
```

search class:

```
class Nodes:
    def succ(self,n):
        raise Exception, "Successor undefined"
    def start (self):
        raise Exception, "Start undefined"
    def goal (self,n):
        raise Exception, "Goal undefined"
```

the class that runs the program:

```
import decant
from breadth_first_search import *

dec = decant.Decant()
print breadth_first_search(dec,[[dec.start()]])
```

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: Please provide a lot more information on how all these parts are supposed to fit together

Comment: First I run the program by running the last bit of code i posted. Then, the program imports class breadth_first_search and then it prints the results of that class. The main problem is in the two_jugs class. Everything else im pretty sure is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is labeling the class `2jugs`.   Variable names in python (including names of classes and functions) as well as many other programming languages cannot start with numbers.  So rename `2jugs` to `two_jugs`.

The [precise rule for identifiers in python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) is the identifier must start with a uppercase (`A-Z`), lowercase (`a-z`), or underscore (`_`).  The following characters of the identifier can also contain digits (`0-9`).  (The rule is specified in [Backus-Naur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form#Example)).

Comment: My apologizes on that and thank you for clearing that out. Btw thanks for editing my question. now it looks as a professional issue. Any help appreciated. Merry xmas